How to implement move constructor with std::any and std::function data members
OS: vxWorks
C++ STandard: 17
Compiler: Clang 16
I'm implementing a move constructor for my class.
I wish to know how do I move or copy data member of type std::any and std::function<void(const std::any&)>.
My implementation for std::function<void(const std::any&)>
this->callback = source.callback;
this->callback.swap(source.callback);
this->callback = std::move(source.callback);

In case of std::function<void(const std::any&)> the target object doesn't posses any value and all call throws std::bad_function_call exception.
As for std::any, all calls to std::any_cast throws std::bad_any_cast
My implementation for std::any
this->callback_data = source.callback_data;
this->callback_data.swap(source.callback_data);

posix_timer.hpp
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

typedef int signal_t;

class PosixTimer
{
public:
    static inline const int signal_rt_min = SIGRTMIN, signal_rt_max = SIGRTMAX;
    using callback_timer_t = std::function<void(const std::any&)>;
    PosixTimer(callback_timer_t callback, const std::any& callback_data, 
        bool periodic = false) : PosixTimer(periodic)
    {
        this->callback = callback;
        this->callback_data = callback_data;
    }

    PosixTimer(){}

    PosixTimer(const PosixTimer& instance)//; = delete;  //Delete copy constructor
    PosixTimer& operator=(const PosixTimer& instance);// = delete; //Delete Copy Assignment 

    PosixTimer(PosixTimer&& source);
    PosixTimer& operator=(PosixTimer&& source);

    ~PosixTimer();
    
    void registerCallback(callback_timer_t callback, const std::any& callback_data);

private:
    static inline std::map<signal_t, bool>  signal_usage_status;
    signal_t                    signal_id;
    static inline std::uint8_t  total_timer_count = 0;
    std::uint8_t                timer_count = 0;
    bool                        periodic;
    std::uint64_t               timeout;// in nano-seconds
    timer_t                     timer_id;
    sigset_t                    mask;
    std::any                    callback_data;
    struct sigevent             sev;
    struct sigaction            sa;
    struct itimerspec           its;
    bool                        timer_valid {false};
    static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc);
    callback_timer_t            callback;
};

posix_timer.cpp
PosixTimer::PosixTimer(PosixTimer &&source)
{
    std::cout << "Inside Move Constructor PosixTimer::PosixTimer(PosixTimer &&source)\n";
    this->timer_id = source.timer_id;
    this->timer_valid = source.timer_valid;
    this->signal_id = source.signal_id;
    this->timer_count = source.timer_count;
    this->periodic = source.periodic;
    this->timeout = source.timeout;// in nano-seconds
    this->mask = source.mask;
    //this->callback_data = source.callback_data;
    this->callback_data.swap(source.callback_data);
    this->sev = source.sev;
    this->sa = source.sa;
    this->its = source.its;
//  this->callback = source.callback;
//  this->callback.swap(source.callback);
    this->callback = std::move(source.callback);
    //Reset source timer_id to 0 and timer validity (timer_valid) to false
    source.timer_id = 0;
    source.timer_valid = false;
}

PosixTimer &PosixTimer::operator=(PosixTimer &&source)
{
    std::cout << "Inside Move Assignment PosixTimer &PosixTimer::operator=(PosixTimer &&source)\n";
    if (this != &source) //performs no operation if you try to assign the object to itself
    {
        this->timer_id = source.timer_id;
        this->timer_valid = source.timer_valid;
        this->signal_id = source.signal_id;
        this->timer_count = source.timer_count;
        this->periodic = source.periodic;
        this->timeout = source.timeout;// in nano-seconds
        this->mask = source.mask;
//      this->callback_data = source.callback_data;
        this->callback_data.swap(source.callback_data);
        this->sev = source.sev;
        this->sa = source.sa;
        this->its = source.its;
//      this->callback = source.callback;
//      this->callback.swap(source.callback);
        this->callback = std::move(source.callback);
        //Reset source timer_id to 0 and timer validity (timer_valid) to false
        source.timer_id = 0;
        source.timer_valid = false; 
    }
    return *this;
}

void PosixTimer::registerCallback(callback_timer_t callback, std::any callback_data)
{
    try
    {
        this->callback_data = callback_data;
        this->callback = callback;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "PosixTimer::registerCallback(callback_timer_t callback, const std::any& callback_data) : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}


main.cpp
#include "posix_timer.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <any>

void handler(const std::any& data)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "Data Type : " << data.type().name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Signal Handler called. Time Delay : " << std::any_cast<int>(data) << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Main::handler : " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    
    
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // std::any data = std::make_any<int>(10);
    std::vector<PosixTimer> vt;
    PosixTimer::initialize();
     {
        PosixTimer t;
        
        bool return_status = t.create(PosixTimer::in_seconds(10), true);
        t.registerCallback(handler, 10);
        vt.push_back(std::move(t));
     }
    while (true)
    {
        sleep(25);
        //vt.at(0).registerCallback(handler, 5);
        vt.at(0).update(PosixTimer::in_seconds(5));
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Output:
Inside constructor PosixTimer::PosixTimer()
PosixTimer::create(std::uint64_t timeout, bool periodic) called
PosixTimer::create(void) called
Signal ID : 34
TIMER START CALLED, Timer ID : 0
Timer Value Sec: 10     nsec: 0
Timer Interval Value Sec: 10    nsec: 0
PosixTimer::registerCallback Callback Data : 10
Inside destructor PosixTimer::~PosixTimer()
timer->callback is empty
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():  bad_function_call
Aborted


Is there any particular reason to have a pair std::function<void(const std::any&)> and std::any instead of just a std::function<void()> (which you can bind any data to/have a stateful lambda)?

std::any a{ std::string{"hello"} }; std::any b; b = std::move(a);

@Artyer I am passing std::any as this is a generic library I've created for the organization and it is used to pass any information as required by the user. However now I am thinking to replace std::any with auto.

@DarkSorrow Just use the type erasure already built into std::function? Instead of PosixTimer(f, data), just have PosixTimer(std::bind_front(f, data)) (or PosixTimer([=]{ f(data); }))?

You should do the rule of 0.  Your business logic class PosixTimer should contain data member fields that already know how to move themselves.  Then you can just
PosixTimer(PosixTimer&&)=default;
PosixTimer(PosixTimer const&)=delete;
PosixTimer& operator=(PosixTimer&&)& =default;
PosixTimer& operator=(PosixTimer const&)& =delete;

and get sane behavior.
What remains is this:
source.timer_id = 0;
source.timer_valid = false; 

you should put them in a type that knows it will clear on move assignment and move construction, either a custom struct or a single-element template.
template<class T, T reset = T{}>
struct reset_on_move
{
  operator T&()&{ return get(); }
  operator T const&()const&{ return get(); }
  operator T()&&{ return std::move(*this).get(); }

  reset_on_move(T in):t(std::move(in)) {}
  reset_on_move():t(reset){}

  reset_on_move(reset_on_move&& rhs):
    t(std::move(rhs).get())
  {}

  reset_on_move& operator=(reset_on_move&& rhs)&
  {
    // we can actually not do this, as later logic is correct
    // in self-assignment case:
    if (std::addressof(rhs) == this)
      return *this;

    t = std::move(rhs).get();
    return *this;
  }
  T& get()&{return t;}
  T const& get()const&{return t;}

  // where the reset happens:
  T get()&&{return std::exchange(t, reset);}
private:
  T t;
};
    

then store:
reset_on_move<int, 0> timer_id;
reset_on_move<bool, false> timer_valid;

which do the "right thing".
However, if you don't want to do this, you can write better move ctor/assignment.
For a move ctor, the first thing you want to do is to actually use initialization not assignment.  I would also blindly apply std::move to every argument:
PosixTimer::PosixTimer(PosixTimer && src):
  timer_id       (std::move(src.timer_id)),
  timer_valid    (std::move(src.timer_valid)),
  signal_id      (std::move(src.signal_id)),

...
just a long set of columns with every argument listed on the left, a std::move and the same argument listed on the right.  The point here is to have a simple, visual pattern that someone can verify as doing nothing interesting.
Amusingly, once you did this, your problem goes away.
The body of the constructor just does this:
 {
   src.timer_id = 0;
   src.timer_valid = false;
 }

which stands out as outside of the pattern, something extra you are doing.
operator= if you write it manually should be structured similarly.  Use whitespace to get aligned colums
member_name        = std::move( other.member_name );
^                  ^ ^                ^

with the caret marked columns aligning so you can visually see the repeated pattern.
All of this boilerplate is nearly pointless, as =default will do it for you if you help the language out a bit, but if you write it yourself you should be super clear you are just doing boilerplate.
The absolute worst of both worlds is a long copy and assignment operator that tries to do exactly what is needed to get the behavior you want.  "I don't use std::move on an integer because there is no point".  In this case, anyone reading your code has to verify that you made no mistakes or errors locally, comparing each member to its type and determine if you where correct in handling how it should optimally be moved.
The use of =default is important, because in the alternatives with 100% reliability this leads to cases where move is missing (with a runtime penalty or a correctness one) when it should be there, or members that you forget to handle, or whatever.

With default move constructor std::function<void(const std::any&)> is not getting moved. I am still getting  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'. If I check if std::function<void(const std::any&)>is empty/valid, I getstd::function<void(const std::any&)>` to be empty.

@DarkSorrow "is not getting moved" - citation needed, please produce a [mcve].  Did you delete the copy constructor?  To create a [mcve], take your code and delete stuff that doesn't prevent the error from happening.  Repeat until you have a minimal program that (a) produces the error and (b) you don't understand why it produces the error.  Share the entire short bit of code that does both, that is a minimal and complete and verifiable example.

You should be relying on the default move constructor (rule of zero), writing a very large move constructor by hand is error prone and is not maintainable. The reason you have a move constructor is because of those two lines
source.timer_id = 0;
source.timer_valid = false;

So let's get rid of them by wrapping them in a struct with a move constructor
#include <utility>
#include <time.h>
struct TimerId
{
    bool timer_valid {false};
    timer_t timer_id{};
    TimerId() = default;

    TimerId(TimerId&& other) noexcept :
    timer_valid(std::exchange(other.timer_valid, false)),
    timer_id(std::exchange(other.timer_id, timer_t{})) {}

    TimerId& operator=(TimerId&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            timer_valid = std::exchange(other.timer_valid, false);
            timer_id = std::exchange(other.timer_id, timer_t{});
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

When you use it in your class you don't need to write a move constructor or move assignment operator. this could change the layout of your class, so if you want to preserve the layout you should split this struct into two.
The same syntax for move-constructing and move-assigning can be used for std::any and std::function, but they both have a default move constructor, so you shouldn't be writing one unless you want a different behavior than the default.
you can replace the code above with the following, if this is used more frequently.
#include <utility>

template <typename T, T Default = T{}> 
struct ClearOnMove
{
    
    T obj = Default;
    ClearOnMove(T obj = Default): obj(std::move(obj)) {};
    ClearOnMove(const ClearOnMove&) = delete;
    ClearOnMove& operator=(const ClearOnMove&) = delete;
    ClearOnMove(ClearOnMove&& other) noexcept :
    obj(std::exchange(other.obj, Default)) {}

    ClearOnMove& operator=(ClearOnMove&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (&other != this)
        {
            obj = std::exchange(other.obj, Default);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

ClearOnMove<timer_t> timer_id;
ClearOnMove<bool> timer_valid;


With default move constructor std::function<void(const std::any&)> is not getting moved. I am still getting  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'. If I check if std::function<void(const std::any&)>is empty/valid, I getstd::function<void(const std::any&)>` to be empty.

@DarkSorrow you shouldn't be calling any function on an object that has been moved-from ... i think this is your issue, to find out who is moving from the object then calling a function on it you need to delete the move constructor then see who is moving it then see who is using that object after it has been moved from.

I've added my test implementation code.

Is their any way I can handle callback?

@DarkSorrow not shown but i think struct sigevent sev; contains this, so now your object is not moveable (if it moves then this is dangling) .... now you need to delete the move constructor and instead use std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PosixTimer>>
